# textarea: append and prepend doesn't work anymore after inserting or deleting text

Tags: jquery, textarea, append, prepend

I use append and prepend to add content to a textarea (#input_messenger). That works fine. As soon as a button (.messenger_reply_button) is hit, the trick happens.

```
$(".messenger_reply_button").click(function() {
    $("#input_messenger").prepend(GetEmailsFromString($(this).attr('content')));
    $("#input_messenger").append(GetHahstagsFromString($(this).attr('content')));
});
```

But... As soon as I add or remove some text manually to the textarea, prepend and append doesn't want to do thing anymore. Test-data is alerted fine, even the content of the textarea. So I'm sure the textarea has been found.

```
alert(#input_messenger.val());
```

Does anyone knows why? And how to solve it?
Check http://jsfiddle.net/U9pum/ for the code!

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle which reproduces your issue.

Comment: I jsfiddled it on [link](http://jsfiddle.net/U9pum/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all it took was getting away from the .append() function.

```
$("textarea#notes").val($("textarea#notes").val() + "New Content");
```

That does the trick and allows for editing. I think it might have something to do with append targeting the HTML structure instead of editing the actual value. Really weird.